# Convert reals in a dataset to it's coordinate form in R^2

Tags: complex

I have a dataset of complex numbers that I want to plot using Graphics, so I'm trying to convert them to coordinate form.
The command I found is

`foo = Replace[#, Complex[a_, b_] :> {a, b}, All] &;`

It works great for all complex numbers not on the real line.

However, I have no idea how to change those on the real line to their coordinate form. For example, I want to change $0.5\mapsto \{0.5, 0\}$.

I mimicked the following command

`foo1 = Replace[#, Real[a_] :> {a, 0}, All] &;`

But which pratically does nothing that I'm aware of. So I would appreciate it if someone can help me find a command that replace real numbers with their coordinates in $R^2$.

Comment: See the built-in function [`ReIm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html)! it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @thorimur thanks so much!